# How can print the numbers present in the given dictionary values in gui python?

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter, dropdown

Help me by modifying my code

**sample code:**

```
values={"High School":"1","Intermediate":"2","Under Graduate":"3","Graduate":"4","Post Graduate":"5"}
c=StringVar()
droplist=OptionMenu(w,c, *values)
droplist.config(width=28)
c.set('Qualification') 
droplist.place(x=260,y=175)
e1=Entry(w,font=( 20 ),bd=2,width=28,textvariable=exp)
e1.place(x=250,y=215)
def a():
    print(c.get())
button1 = Button(w, text="Print",command=lambda: a())
button1.place(x=300,y=235)
```

**Expected output :**
    1 .
**Displayed output:**
   High School

Comment: I'm not totally clear on what you're asking. Where do you want the output to go to, exactly? I see a `Button` and an `OptionMenu` and a `print` which one are you trying to use? And what is determining what gets output to wherever it's supposed to go?

Comment: when I click on `button` it should `print` the values like `1` or `2` given in the first line of code as per our selection in `dropdown` list

Comment: we are going to select a option from `OptionMenu` and it should `print` the adjacent values given to them in **first line** of code.

Answer (score 0):

If i have understood right you want to print the value selected in the option in the GUI. You can add the output label as below

```
def a():
    print(c.get())
    value = c.get()
    Label(text="Displayed output: ").place(x=260, y = 300)
    new_text = Label(text=value).place(x=400, y=300)
```

In your sample code you are getting the option selected, you could just pass it to the Label widget which is a standard Tkinter widget used to display a text

**Output**

[image]

Reference: http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/label.htm